# Unknown look-behind group near index in Java 8 for named regex grouop

Tags: regex, java-8, regex-group

I have a pattern that I am trying to parse in Java 8, but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. I am trying to create named grouped regex. Ant help would be appreciated.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String p = ".*(/p/(?<listingId>[a-zA-Z0-9\\-].*)/(?< sellerOfferId>[a-zA-Z0-9\\-])(/)?$";
        Pattern.compile(p);
    }
}
```

This throws an error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unknown look-behind group near index 66
.*(/p/(?<listingId>[a-zA-Z0-9\-].*)/(?< sellerOfferId>[a-zA-Z0-9\-])(/)?$
                                                                  ^
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1924)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.group0(Pattern.java:2829)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:2018)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:1964)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.group0(Pattern.java:2854)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:2018)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:1964)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1665)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1337)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1022)
    at com.myproject.test.Test.main(Test.java:9)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There seem to be two problems in your regex.

- First, there is an unwanted space before `sellerOfferId` in named group.
- Second, there is a missing `)` at the end to make parenthesis balanced.

Once you fix that, your Pattern no longer gives any error. Try this updated Java code,

```
String p = ".*(/p/(?<listingId>[a-zA-Z0-9\\-].*)/(?<sellerOfferId>[a-zA-Z0-9\\-])(/)?$)";
                                                    ^ removed space here              ^ put this missing )
Pattern.compile(p);
```

Now it no longer gives `PatternSyntaxException`.